# How to get Instagram comment parent id and identify if it top-level or reply

Tags: php, comments, instagram, webhooks

I'm working on Instagram API, I need to identify whether the comment of a specific id is a top-level comment or reply on a comment, in case it is a reply then what is the parent comment id.
I searched about any related fields in the API documentation (link below) but nothing meets these needs.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/comment/

All details API provides is the edge "replies" which get the children, while what I'm looking for is to know if it is top-level or reply comment and get the parent comment id if it has.

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: sadly no, we have changed the project idea a little bit around this point to solve this issue

Comment: Could you please describe the idea? Or give me a hint to find another solution?

Comment: we treat all comments regardless their level (top or reply) as a top-level comments

Answer (score 0):

Now the "parent_id" field is available as part of the Webhook's payload.
All you need to do is to subscribe on Instagram Webhooks product to the "comments" field on your Facebook developer app and you'll receive the "parent_id" property if this comment was created on another IG comment.

```
{
  "field": "comments",
  "value": {
    "from": {
      "id": "232323232",
      "username": "test"
    },
    "media": {
      "id": "123123123",
      "media_product_type": "FEED"
    },
    "id": "17865799348089039",
    "**parent_id**": "1231231234",
    "text": "This is an example."
  }
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/instagram/#comments

*ID of parent IG Comment if this comment was created on another IG Comment (i.g. a reply to another comment)*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30075043)